# How to download internet(http) file in SL4 out of browser project?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

my function open a internet page in pop-up browser before to download a file. But after I change to SL4 and out-of-browser, seems the pop-up is no longer working

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.PopupWindow(_uri, "Report", null);
```

and then I also tried HttpWebRequest and WebBrowser. Seems they both won't ask the user to download the file or not, but just stay silence.

Comment: Can you check the value of `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.IsPopupWindowAllowed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I sloved this by checking when OOB mode, use Shell command for the http URL, then a download box will prompt directly.